# xml to html parser for iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, xml, webview

I have Flash xml of eg

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <screen type="TEXT_PIC_RIGHT" asset="WT01010.swf" audio="WT01010.mp3" filter="learningObjectives">

        <area type="title"><![CDATA[Chapter Learning Objectives]]></area>

        <area type="text"><![CDATA[After completing this chapter, you should be able to:]]></area>

            <area type="textbullet"><bullet><![CDATA[1.]]></bullet><text><![CDATA[Describe the primary functions and the 2 main divisions of the nervous system]]></text></area>

            <area type="textbullet"><bullet><![CDATA[2.]]></bullet><text><![CDATA[Identify the subdivisions of the <font color="#0000FF"><b><a href="event:glossary,peripheral nervous system (PNS)">peripheral nervous system (PNS)</a></b></font> and how they operate]]></text></area>
</screen>
```

It used to display webpage Using Flash. How Can i convert it to Html so that i can display that page in a webview? Can anyone one help me with this?? thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any question is related to Converting any xml format to any other format i always recommend using XSLT because XSLT is made exactly for that purpose and therefor the best way to do it.

So i'm not familiar with the iphone but i'm pretty sure there is an XSLT implementation for it.