# XML to HTMl to use in the UIwebView

Tags: html, objective-c, xml, ipad, uiwebview

How i can convert a XML file into a HTML file in developing Ipad application. Because i have aDocument in .XML format. I have to convert it into html and then i have to use that content in the UIWebview.

Please guide me with any sample or tutorial available

Thanks

Rizwan

Comment: [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165875/xml-to-html-parser-for-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

To convert XML to HTML, I would suggest you investigate [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT).

It is an XML-based language for parsing an XML file and converting it to another format, typically used to generate HTML from XML, or to convert to another XML format.